# Branch descriptions in Git

Tags: git, branch, task-tracking

Is there a way in Git to have a 'description' for branches?

While I try to use descriptive names, working for a while on a single branch sometimes dampens my memory of why I made some of the other topic branches. I try to use descriptive names for the branches, but I think a 'description' (short note about the purpose of the branch) would be nice.

Comment: I had a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876142/git-how-to-keep-a-file-common-across-all-branches). I use that file to document branches and why they exist (among other things).

Comment: This would be a really useful feature. git branch -a could show the descriptions next to the branch names. Maybe git notes will support notes on branches as well as commits in the future?

Comment: Branch descriptions can't be pushed, so they are pretty useless unless you want to send messages to yourself.

Comment: @nurettin True but my request was for private stuff anyway. I just wanted to remember why I cut the branch.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Git 1.7.9 supports this. From the [1.7.9 release notes](https://github.com/gitster/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.9.txt):

```
 * "git branch --edit-description" can be used to add descriptive text
   to explain what a topic branch is about.
```

You can see that feature introduced back in September 2011, with commits [6f9a332](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f9a332144cda5f4d7e6e03c37fb17f8ffac1fe3), [739453a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/739453a3fb74ade725243ac972f02ba1aedabdf6), [b7200e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7200e839737491dfe8f0297fba54621fd7d7583):

```
struct branch_desc_cb {
  const char *config_name;
  const char *value;
};

--edit-description::
```

> Open an editor and edit the text to explain what the branch is for, to be used by various other commands (e.g. `request-pull`).

Note that it won't work for a detached HEAD branch.

That description is used by the script request-pull: see [commit c016814783](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0168147831fce00975949213eef3471b7a2b76b), but also [`git merge --log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/898eacd8ada2d012f977948350ed60845e238037).

> [`request-pull`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-request-pull.txt) is a script used to summarizes the changes between two commits to the standard output, and includes the given URL in the generated summary.

[From @AchalDave] Unfortunately, you can't push descriptions since they're stored in your config, making it useless for the sake of documenting branches in a team.

Comment: @Owen: The only way I know of at the moment is to use `git config branch.topic.description` to show the description for branch `topic`. It's stored in the `.git/config` file.

Comment: @GregHewgill Thank you. With a few aliases that's actually not a bad way to view it. Now if only `git branch` would show the descriptions in the list...

Comment: @Owen: I wrote a `git branches` command that shows the branch description instead of the last commit message (this was for work and I don't have a public distribution available at this time).

Comment: At this time, gist quoted in previous comment doesn't seem to be available, but this appears to be similar: https://gist.github.com/carlosayam/5316969

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't push descriptions since they're stored in your config, making it useless for the sake of documenting branches in a team.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues sadly your gist link is broken

Comment: You can also use `git config branch.<branch_name>.note 'This is a note'`

You can see the note as `git config branch.<branch_name>.note`

Comment: I recently found a [npm package](https://github.com/bahmutov/git-branches) that makes it easy to list out your branch descriptions in case people are interested.

Comment: when I attempt git --edit-description, I get "fatal: cannot edit description of more than one branch".

Comment: You can show description with little hack: `GIT_EDITOR=cat git branch --edit-description`

Comment: Is there a way to edit the description without an interactive editor session?

Comment: What's the standard way to **view** the description? Just run `git branch --edit-description` again?

Answer (score 40):

If you *do* end up using the README, create a [git alias](http://davidwalsh.name/git-aliases) modifying `git checkout` so that your README is displayed every time you switch branches.

For example, add this in ~/.gitconfig, under **[alias]**

```
cor = !sh -c 'git checkout $1 && cat README' -
```

After this, you can run `git cor <branch_name>` to switch branch *and* display the README of the branch you're switching to.

Comment: For me $1 variable is not working — it contains nothing. I don't know why (I'm using version `1.7.11-msysgit.1`). I'm using $0 instead. And everything is fine.

Comment: @shytikov for git aliases that use arguments, for portability, I use a quick function instead of "`sh -c`"; e.g,. `alias = "!f() { git checkout "${1}" && cat README.md; }; f"` _(brackets and quotes unnecessary in this case, just included for completeness in case they are needed for something more complicated.)_

Comment: @michael_n your alias, is that a bash alias or a git alias

Comment: Only problem is that if README isnt't in the folder you are in when you checkout it just complains.

Comment: @UpAndAdam it's a git alias, defined in `~/.gitconfig`, under `[alias]`, and the name of the alias is in fact (and understandably confusingly) called `alias` from my actual config (I should have renamed it `cor` for this example to be consistent). My actual `alias` alias is:  `alias = "!f() { git config --get-regexp "^alias.${1}$" ; }; f"`  Usage: `git alias {alias_name}` or `git alias {alias_regexp}`. Analogous to the bash `alias` command, e.g., `$ alias ll` yields (for me): `alias ll='ls -l'`; and `$ git alias br` yields: `alias.br branch -v --list` (also could use: `$ git alias 'b.*'`)

Answer (score 40):

Use `git branch --edit-description` to set or edit a branch description.

Here is a shell function to show branches similar to `git branch` but with descriptions appended.

```sh
# Shows branches with descriptions
function gb() {
  current=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
  branches=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/ | sed 's|refs/heads/||')
  for branch in $branches; do
    desc=$(git config branch.$branch.description)
    if [ $branch == $current ]; then
      branch="* \033[0;32m$branch\033[0m"
     else
       branch="  $branch"
     fi
     echo -e "$branch \033[0;36m$desc\033[0m"
  done
}
```

Here is what `gb` looks like, shown here as text in case the image rots:

```
$ gb
* logging Log order details.  Waiting for clarification from business.
  master 
  sprocket Adding sprockets to the parts list.  Pending QA approval.
```

And as an image, so you can see the colors:

[image]

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer (posted more than one year prior)?

Comment: *["Unfortunately, you can't push descriptions since they're stored in your config, making it useless for the sake of documenting branches in a team."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git#comment26551641_8858853)*

Answer (score 31):

The `README` [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2108455/6309) by [Chris J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165119/chris-j) can work, provided it is setup with a **[custom merge driver defined in a `.gitattribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp/930495#930495)**.
That way, the *local* version of the `README` is always preserved during merges.

The "description" for branches is also know as a "comment" associated with that meta data, and it is not supported.

At least, with a `README` file, you can, for any branch, do a:

```
$ git show myBranch:README
```

If your README is at the root directory of your REPO, it  will work from any path, since the path used by [`git show`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html) is an absolute one from the top directory of said repo.

Comment: Does everyone on the team have to be aware of this and set it in their .gitattribute individually if they want it?  If so, it seems to me this would be difficult to manage, and chances of people actually doing it would be slim.

Comment: @DonHatch: You normally check the `.gitattributes` file into your repository, so no, it would just work for everyone. This unfortunately doesn't seem to work when merging through some web-based interfaces though, e.g., when using pull requests in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 25):

There are two popular suggestions here:

1. `git branch --edit-description` : We don't like this because you can't push it. Maybe I can remember what the branches I created do, but my team sure can't.
2. `README` file pr. branch. This is a pain during merges: Super-prone to merge conflicts and we'll be pulling in `README` from branches when we merge feature branches. Diffs between branches are also a pain.

We've decided to create an orphan `branches-readme` branch. Orphan branches are branches with their own separate history - you may know them from Github's `gh-pages` branches. This orphan branch contains a single `README` file. It has contents like:

```
master:
    The default branch
mojolicious:
    Start using Mojolicious
branch-whatever:
    Description of the whatever branch
```

It is push-able and merge-friendly. View the `README` from any branch with:

```
git show branches-readme:README
```

Disadvantages are that you need to checkout the weird orphan branch when you want to update the `README` and the `README` doesn't auto-update as branches get renamed, come or go. That is fine for us, though.

Do it like:

```
git checkout --orphan branches-readme
# All the files from the old branch are marked for addition - skip that
git reset --hard
# There are no files yet - an empty branch
ls
vi README
# put in contents similar to above
git add README
git commit -m "Initial description of the branches we already have"
git push origin branches-readme
# get all your original files back
git checkout master
```

Similary, individual team members can also create their own  `branches-$user` orphan branches describing their own private branches if they want to, as long as they don't push them to the team.

With further tooling this could also be integrated with the output of `git branch`. To that end, perhaps a `README.yaml` file could be considered instead of a plain `README`.

Comment: One just *could* have the README in master. That would add clutter but be always accessible.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Sure, but then adding a new branch would require a commit to master even though the change has nothing whatsoever to do with master. Also, when branching off of master, you'll have a copy of the README in all the branches, which is i a mess.

Comment: I love this answer. Simple and general.

Answer (score 13):

```
git config --global --add alias.about '!describe() { git config branch."$1".description; }; describe'
```

Command will define a global option `alias.about` as shell expression. Running `git about <branch>` in a repository will display branch's description if set.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it so it just looks at the branch I'm on -- `"!describe() { git config branch.\"$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)\".description; }; describe"`

Comment: @aug - I needed to drop the backslashes in front of the argument quotes to get this to work: `git config --global --add alias.about '!describe() { git config branch."$(git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD)".description; }; describe'`

Answer (score 11):

Here's a `git` `alias` that lets you both set and read descriptions on the current branch:

```
git config --global --add alias.about '!describe() { msg="$1"; git config branch."$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)".description ${msg:+"$msg"}; }; describe'
```

Usage/examples:

```
(develop) $ git about
(develop) $ git about message
(develop) $ git about
message
(develop) $ git about "this is a new message"
(develop) $ git about
this is a new message
(develop) $ git checkout -b test_branch
Switched to a new branch 'test_branch'
(test_branch) $ git about
(test_branch) $ git about "this is the test branch"
(test_branch) $ git about
this is the test branch
(test_branch) $ git checkout -
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
(develop) $ git about
this is a new message
```

Special thanks to @Felicio for the answer that got me started.

Comment: Nice! Is it can be compile to shell or ohmyzsh?

Comment: It would be even greater if we could push/pull those kind of info! No way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a possible implementation of the `git branches` command Greg Hewgill alluded to:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub clean {
    map { s/^[\s\*]*\s// } @_;
    map { s/\s*$// } @_;
    return @_;
}

sub descr {
    $_ = `git config branch.@_.description`;
    s/\s*$//;
    return $_;
};
sub indent {
    $_ = shift;
    s/^/      /mg;
    return $_;
};

my @branches = clean `git branch --color=never --list`;
my %merged = map { $_ => 1 } clean `git branch --color=never --merged`;

for my $branch (@branches) {
    my $asis = `git branch --list --color=always $branch`;
    $asis =~ s/\s*$//;
    print "  $asis";
    print " \033[33m(merged)\033[0m" if ($merged{$branch} and $branch ne "master");
    print "\n";

    print indent descr $branch;
    print "\n";
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Say you want to create a branch

```
git branch branch-20200328
git notes add branch-20200328 -m "This branch is for whatever"
git notes show branch-20200328
```

Comment: This isn't as helpful as it first appears because the note is attached to the branch in it's current state. If you push a new commit to the branch, ```git show branch``` doesn't show the note anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach comments to tags:

```
git tag -m 'this was a very good commit' tag1
```

By convention, you could have tags related to your branch names or you could use tag -f to keep a commented tag at the head of your topic branches.

Comment: this is not ideal because it does not track the head of the branch

Comment: Check the annotation: git tag -n

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
git config --get-regexp "branch.*.description"
```

Comment: See also a dedicated question regarding printing the branch descriptions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15058844/94687

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
git config branch.<branch name>.description
```

To give credit where credit is due:
https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/git-branches-with-descriptions/

Comment: This was added in a version of git that was released after I added the question. The accepted answer mentions this.

Comment: Ah yes. It is mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Though a shortcut, isn't this essentially identical to the accepted answer? - *["Unfortunately, you can't push descriptions since they're stored in your config, making it useless for the sake of documenting branches in a team."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git#comment26551641_8858853)*

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)'s 2012 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858853/6309), Git 1.7.9 (Q1 2012) also included some checks for `git branch --edit-description`:

See [commit c2d17ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2d17ba3db0d2b14daf04e69a8c5ec73b023c1fe) (05 Feb 2012) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d88698e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d88698ec0b4b91e61b0fe3e00d7451abcdf4cd44), 10 Feb 2012)</sup>

> ### [`branch --edit-description`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2d17ba3db0d2b14daf04e69a8c5ec73b023c1fe): protect against mistyped branch name

> It is very easy to mistype the branch name when editing its description, e.g.
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b my-topic master
> : work work work
> : now we are at a good point to switch working something else
> $ git checkout master
> : ah, let's write it down before we forget what we were doing
> $ git branch --edit-description my-tpoic
> ```
>
> The command does not notice that branch 'my-tpoic' does not exist.
> It is not lost (it becomes description of an unborn my-tpoic branch), but is not very useful.
> So detect such a case and error out to reduce the grief factor from this common mistake.
>
> This incidentally also errors out `--edit-description` when the HEAD points at an unborn branch (immediately after "`init`", or "`checkout --orphan`"), because at that point, you do not even have any commit that is part of your history and there is no point in describing how this particular branch is different from the branch it forked off of, which is the useful bit of information the branch description is designed to capture.
>
> We may want to special case the unborn case later, but that is outside the scope of this patch to prevent more common mistakes before 1.7.9 series gains too much widespread use.

---

While [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)'s 2012 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858853/6309) is accurate, using `git branch --edit-description` can lead to:

```
fatal: could not unset 'branch.main.description'
```

"[`GIT_EDITOR=: git branch --edit-description`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/272be0db8b732617245930b92c9a79a1fc5b4398/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L273)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---edit-description))</sup> resulted in failure, which has been corrected with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022).

See [commit e288b3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e288b3de35eaaf3febe07cd56565d8e8af17fb1e) (30 Sep 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 272be0d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/272be0db8b732617245930b92c9a79a1fc5b4398), 17 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e288b3de35eaaf3febe07cd56565d8e8af17fb1e): do not fail a no-op `--edit-desc`

> Imagine running "[`git branch --edit-description`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e288b3de35eaaf3febe07cd56565d8e8af17fb1e/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L241)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---edit-description))</sup> while on a branch without the branch description, and then exit the editor after emptying the edit buffer, which is the way to tell the command that you changed your mind and you do not want the description after all.
>
> The command should just happily oblige, adding no branch description for the current branch, and exit successfully.
> But it fails to do so:
>
> ```
> $ git init -b main
> $ git commit --allow-empty -m commit
> $ GIT_EDITOR=: git branch --edit-description
> fatal: could not unset 'branch.main.description'
> ```
>
> The end result is OK in that the configuration variable does not exist in the resulting repository, but we should do better.
> If we know we didn't have a description, and if we are asked not to have a description by the editor, we can just return doing nothing.
>
> This of course introduces TOCTOU.

([Time-of-check to time-of-use (**TOCTOU**)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use): a class of software bugs caused by a race condition involving the checking of the state of a part of a system (such as a security credential) and the use of the results of that check.)

> If you add a branch description to the same branch from another window, while you had the editor open to edit the description, and then exit the editor without writing anything there, we'd end up not removing the description you added in the other window.
> But you are fooling yourself in your own repository at that point, and if it hurts, you'd be better off not doing so ;-).

---

Also: "[`git branch --edit-description`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4050354b1464d33b829f883ba7166d94d5dd7571/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L273)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---edit-description))</sup> on an unborn branch misleadingly said that no such branch exists, which has been corrected with Git 2.39 (Q4 2022).

See [commit bcfc82b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bcfc82bd48f518c8939090748516ad21bb079720) (08 Oct 2022) by [Rubén Justo (`rjusto`)](https://github.com/rjusto).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4050354](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4050354b1464d33b829f883ba7166d94d5dd7571), 17 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bcfc82bd48f518c8939090748516ad21bb079720): description for non-existent branch errors
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Rubén Justo</sup>

> When the repository does not yet have commits, some errors describe that there is no branch:
>
> ```
> $ git init -b first
>
> $ git branch --edit-description first
> error: No branch named 'first'.
>
> $ git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream
> fatal: branch 'first' does not exist
>
> $ git branch -c second
> error: refname refs/heads/first not found
> fatal: Branch copy failed
> ```
>
> That "first" branch is unborn but to say it doesn't exists is confusing.
>
> Options "-c" (copy) and "-m" (rename) show the same error when the origin branch doesn't exists:
>
> ```
> $ git branch -c non-existent-branch second
> error: refname refs/heads/non-existent-branch not found
> fatal: Branch copy failed
>
> $ git branch -m non-existent-branch second
> error: refname refs/heads/non-existent-branch not found
> fatal: Branch rename failed
> ```
>
> Note that "`--edit-description`" without an explicit argument is already considering the *empty repository* circumstance in its error.
> Also note that "`-m`" on the initial branch it is an allowed operation.
>
> Make the error descriptions for those branch operations with unborn or non-existent branches, more informative.
>
> This is the result of the change:
>
> ```
> $ git init -b first
>
> $ git branch --edit-description first
> error: No commit on branch 'first' yet.
>
> $ git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream
> fatal: No commit on branch 'first' yet.
>
> $ git branch -c second
> fatal: No commit on branch 'first' yet.
>
> $ git branch [-c/-m] non-existent-branch second
> fatal: No branch named 'non-existent-branch'.
> ```

---

With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), "[`git branch --edit-description @{-1}`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c2058ea237604d3ba7570f355c7832b9e467d6cb/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L273)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---edit-description))</sup> is now a way to edit branch description of the branch you were on before switching to the current branch.

See [commit 0dc4e5c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dc4e5c57498cc142cbcc9e8a5f0667368d7c860) (11 Oct 2022) by [Rubén Justo (`rjusto`)](https://github.com/rjusto).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c2058ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2058ea237604d3ba7570f355c7832b9e467d6cb), 21 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0dc4e5c57498cc142cbcc9e8a5f0667368d7c860): support for shortcuts like `@{-1}`, completed
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Rubén Justo</sup>

> branch command with options "edit-description", "set-upstream-to" and "unset-upstream" expects a branch name.
> Since [ae5a6c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae5a6c3684c378bc32c1f6ecc0e6dc45300c14c1) (`checkout`: implement "`@{-N}`" shortcut name for N-th last branch, 2009-01-17, Git v1.6.2-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8712b3cdb0495f5a56b91cd67e2697412447a886)), a branch can be specified using shortcuts like `@{-1}`.
> Those shortcuts need to be resolved when considering the arguments.
>
> We can modify the description of the previously checked out branch with:
>
> ```
>  $ git branch --edit--description @{-1}
> ```
>
> We can modify the upstream of the previously checked out branch with:
>
> ```
>  $ git branch --set-upstream-to upstream @{-1}
>  $ git branch --unset-upstream @{-1}
> ```

---

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), error messages given when working on an unborn branch that is checked out in another worktree have been improved.

See [commit 3521c63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3521c6321350cf1432f4772efa09db8bec0aa331), [commit a675ad1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a675ad1708383f47883d0bb0b2dada827a295acd), [commit 7a6ccdf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a6ccdfb4eeb9d55893eae9b2c7e573b92f3d01d), [commit d7f4ca6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d7f4ca61b51da5655df09277309380794ba1bd19), [commit 2e8af49](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e8af499ff6e166a5f54f18cf3d1fa8f5d9bde38) (27 Mar 2023) by [Rubén Justo (`rjusto`)](https://github.com/rjusto).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d3f2e4a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3f2e4ab13f54ec3de1ac752e41d30847974c140), 15 May 2023)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a6ccdfb4eeb9d55893eae9b2c7e573b92f3d01d): description for orphan branch errors
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Rubén Justo</sup>

> In [bcfc82b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bcfc82bd48f518c8939090748516ad21bb079720) ("`branch`: description for non-existent branch errors", 2022-10-08, Git v2.39.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4050354b1464d33b829f883ba7166d94d5dd7571) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4732897cf0a255a23dca9e97b65cea40cd06c5a8)) we checked the HEAD in the current worktree to detect if the branch to operate with is an orphan branch, so as to avoid the confusing error: "No branch named...".
>
> If we are asked to operate with an orphan branch in a different working tree than the current one, we need to check the HEAD in that different working tree.
>
> Let's extend the check we did in [bcfc82b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bcfc82bd48f518c8939090748516ad21bb079720), to check the HEADs in all worktrees linked to the current repository, using the helper introduced in [31ad6b6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31ad6b61bdaa408f2616d7dca0f6d66ee4742c8d) ("`branch`: add `branch_checked_out()` helper", 2022-06-15, Git v2.38.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2d01098fb69567f7a354fa8f89a6f23d522ed82) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55ece90cddf212654bd9271654c442737f8bd29e)).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that feature is not currently supported. I think your best bet is to create a description text file, a README basically, in the branch that has the information that you want.

Comment: I'd have to worry about (not) merging this file across branches. Wouldn't I?

Comment: @KaspervandenBerg: Maybe just leave a comment instead of pulling out the -1-card, then wait some time, and if the asker is not willing to change the post, but you see he/she/it visited this site in the meanwhile, spell it. Or do _you_ regularly check all your answers given to see if they are still correct?

Comment: @phresnel: good point; my intention was to help future askers of this question and have good anwers go to top and incorrect ones to bottom, it was not to "punish" Chris J and cause him to loose reputation.  Unfortunately the site says my vote is locked :(.

Comment: @KaspervandenBerg: I was a bit quick to suspect you of punishing, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer seems like overkill to me.  I'd be inclined to maintain a per branch description file that is a normal source controlled file, say `master.txt`, `dev.txt`, etc. and if there is an unwieldy number or branches I'd create a hierarchy to better organize it.

Comment: Then you'd have to worry about merging these files to every other branch, or remember to use `git show master:dev.txt` which is not any simpler than the selected answer.

Answer (score -4):

Use

```
git branch --list -v
```

to show an upstream branch:

```
git branch --list -vv
```

Add `-r` to show remotes only or `-a` to show remotes and local.

Comment: Useful as these are, I'm looking for something custom. A note of some kind attached to a reference.

Comment: It does not show descriptions. I think this answer is misleading.