# Tracked files kept secret in a branch

Tags: git

I have a question I can't solve out by myself. To put it simply, I'm wondering if there's a way to track a file in a branch while keeping it secret so that it's not added into other branches when this branch is merged into another one.

To make it clearer, say you have a branch `b1`.
Then you add an new file `f` and you track it (`git add f` / `git commit`).
When you merge `b1` into another branch `b2`, the file `f` is added to the working tree.
I simply would like to avoid this and keep f "private" to b1.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea somehow.. At a guess, it's either a password file or a local database? There's probably a better way. [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)

Answer (score 1):

If you can version a similar `.gitattributes` in all branches, you could set up a **[merge driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910444/git-merge-s-theirs-needed-but-i-know-it-doesnt-exist/1910479#1910479)** which would ostensibly ignore the file '`f`' content.

So `f` wouldn't be private on the other branches, but at least it would be empty.
If you need to see its content, you still can ask git to show the `f` content from the right branch. See for instance "[Branch descriptions in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git/2108832#2108832)"

```
git show mySecretBranch:f
```