# Can I add a description to Git branches?

Tags: git, branch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Branch descriptions in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git)

Sometimes I find it difficult to remember why exactly I made a new Git branch. Is there any way I can add a description to a branch? I can of course add this information in my first commit to the branch, but it would be nice to be able to do something like this:

```
git checkout -b -m"Branch for that really good idea" mybranch
```

And then do some other work and forget about my idea altogether, because I can do

```
git checkout -descr mybranch<Enter>
Output: Your description: "Branch for that really good idea"
```

I know about git-notes, but it's being used to add information to commits, so it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226953/branch-descriptions-in-git-continued and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git