# Branch descriptions in git, continued

Tags: git, branch, task-tracking

I've been working on a system to keep a BRANCH_DESCRIPTION file whenever I create a topic branch in git.  Like others have mentioned, I too sometimes forget what I created a branch for, even though I try to give it a descriptive name.

I have been primarily working off the SO question [How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-sp/930495#930495), but I've run into a case where the custom merge driver does not get called, so the file from the topic branch being merged in overwrites the local branch.  For example:

```
git checkout master
echo "mainline" > BRANCH_DESCRIPTION
git add BRANCH_DESCRIPTION
git commit -m'Added BRANCH_DESCRIPTION file'
git checkout -b topic_branch
echo "this branch is used to fix the bug where [...]" > BRANCH_DESCRIPTION
git commit -m'Updated BRANCH_DESCRIPTION'
[code, code, code ...]
[git, git, git ...]
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff topic_branch
```

At this point BRANCH_DESCRIPTION will simply be overwritten since the master branch's description has not changed regardless if a custom merge driver has been setup for the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your rationale for storing a branch description in the content being track?

Comment: I'm not particularly attached to the idea.  The other SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git got me going in this direction and so I started checking it out.  What I believe you are alluding to is that this information is more metadata than content that should be tracked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `git notes` for this purpose.

In your branch do `git notes add -m "this branch is for blah blah"`

Then write a post-commit in your repo with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
git notes show HEAD~1
git notes copy HEAD~1 HEAD
```

Additionally add a `git notes remove HEAD~1` if you want.

Use `git notes show` to see what the branch is for.

Comment: I have been experimenting with this and noticed that using "git reset" will lose the note.  I'm guessing an alias on git reset could fix this case.

Answer (score 10):

Git now supports this by running `git branch --edit-description`

This answer has a [nice writeup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858853)

Comment: The description is local, though. You cannot commit it.