# Git: How to see old version of a file (before it was added to the staging area/index)?

Tags: git

Suppose I changed my file `foo.txt` and run `git add foo.txt`. Now `foo.txt` appears in the list of the "changes to be committed".

Now I would like to see my `foo.txt` *before* these changes. How can I do it with `git`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
git show HEAD:foo.txt
```

In general, this syntax is very useful for seeing a file from a particular commit without touching your working tree.  For example, if you want to see what `README.txt` was like in the grand-parent of commit `f414f31` you can do:

```
git show f414f31^^:README.txt
```

*Update: as [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) comments below, it's important to note here that the path here must be the full path from the root of the working tree, even if you're currently in a subdirectory.*

However, when staging changes, one does tend to be more often interested in differences, which is what [Abizern interpreted your question as asking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461945/simple-question-about-git/7461965#7461965).  A simple way of thinking about those commands is:

- `git diff` means "what changes haven't I staged yet?"
- `git diff --cached` means "what changes have I already staged?"

Comment: +1, but as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git/2108832#2108832, and illustrated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364147/how-to-get-just-one-file-from-another-branch/2364223#2364223, you need to use the full path form the root directory of the repo when using `git show`.

Comment: Thanks, VonC - I've updated my answer to include that useful reminder.

Answer (score 6):

I *think* what you're asking is about diffs (which show the differences between versions of files)

I've written about them [here](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/3464927214/getting-a-diff-between-the-working-tree-and-other)

But a summary diagram is:

[image]