# Print branch description

Tags: git, git-branch

Git supports an option to the `branch` command called `--edit-description`, which the man page states to be used by "various" other commands.  One command (at least by default) that it is not used by is `git-branch`, when used to simply list the local branches.

Is there way to get `git-branch` to show the branch descriptions?  The verbose option looks like it just adds the last commit on the branch.

To be clear, I'd like something like the following:

```
> git branch
* master      I am the alpha and the omega
  bugfix1     This is the fix to that thing
  future      Transition to the new architecture
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git

Comment: Who's answer gets me branch descriptions when I issue a 'git branch`?  Owens?  Or are you saying that I need to do something with a README?  I was looking at this question right before I decided to post this quesiton.

Comment: @bpw1621 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108405/branch-descriptions-in-git#comment13650058_8858853 – Apparently there is no other built-in way—yet—to show the descriptions.

Comment: @poke okay if the answer is there is no way to accomplish what I am asking with a builtin method then that is an answer.  If there is any other way to get what I am looking for besides what is detailed in the issue you and number5 have sighted that is again valuable information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I confirm there is no way for now to display the description of the branch with `git branch` (as opposed to `git config`, see last part of this answer below).

[This thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/More-support-on-branch-description-td7204093.html) includes

> > The coming v1.7.9 will introduce branch description, mainly used in
> > integration process. I think we could make it useful for users who
> > don't extensively use request-pull/format-patch. Showing a short
> > summary along with branch name in "`git branch`" would be nice.
>
> I agree that it would be nice to give users access to the information even
> if the branch ends up being merged to the master branch by you and never
> leaves your repository by itself.
>
> You however are misguided to say "Showing a short summary along...".
>
> The branch description support is to give users a place to record detailed explanation about a branch, similar in size to what you would normally place in a log message of a commit or a cover letter of a series.
> There wasn't any convenient place to do so for a branch that is (1) inherently a moving target while it is being developed and (2) is not a good match for tags and notes.
>
> There already is a good place for a brief summary and it is called "branch name". Name your branches just like you name your functions.

The suggested patch "[`git branch --verbose-format`](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/186727)" is not yet completed.

So the [script](https://gist.github.com/pdfr/2658582) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058844/print-branch-description#comment21172842_15058844) by [poke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216074/poke), remains (with a `git alias`) one possible solution:

```
#!/bin/perl
 
$output= `git branch`;
 
foreach my $line (split(/^/, $output)) {
  my ($is_current, $name) = split(/\s+/, $line);
  my $description = `git config branch.$name.description`;
 
  $description =~ s/\s+$//;
  printf("%1s %-22s %s\n", $is_current, $name, $description);
}
```

---

[Philip Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717355/philip-oakley) suggests in the comments:

> You can display the branch description using a `git config` command.
>
> To show all branch descriptions, I have the alias
>
> ```
> brshow = config --get-regexp 'branch.*.description'
> ```
>
> , and for the current HEAD I have
>
> ```
> brshow1 = !git config --get "branch.$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD).description".
> ```

Comment: Any way to restore the default color coding? This script does the job but also eliminates the color coding from the console o/p.

Comment: @VonC Is the patch "git branch --verbose-format" still in works?

Thanks

Comment: @Abhinav Not sure since 5 years ago. You have `git branch -vv`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--v

Comment: You can display the branch description using a `git config` command. To show all branch descriptions I have the alias `brshow = config --get-regexp 'branch.*.description'`, and for the current HEAD I have `brshow1 = !git config --get "branch.$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD).description"`.

Comment: @PhilipOakley Nicely done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility;

Comment: @VonC Thank you. I hope to propose something like it upstream (`--show-description` and `show-all-description` possibly)

Comment: @PhilipOakley that would be great, indeed.

Comment: Quite frankly, this is ridiculous.  I'll improve the support for branch descriptions in git, by implementing and submitting patches upstream.

Comment: @dsimic Great, I will follow that with interest.

Comment: @VonC Thanks.  Though, it will take some time, because I already have a whole bunch of pending patches in my queue, for various open-source projects.

Comment: I'm thinking about adding new `git-description` command to deal with the branch descriptions, which would be similar to the already existing `git-notes` command. May I know your thoughts about such an approach?

Comment: Actually, it might be simpler and better to add new `--show-description` and `--remove-description` options to the `git-branch` command, because adding new command would probably not be warranted.  The next step could be to allow the descriptions to be displayed when listing branches, e.g. by adding new `--show-descriptions` suboption for the `--list` option.

Comment: @dsimic True: you can discuss this on https://public-inbox.org/git/

Comment: Sure, I'll discuss the whole idea and the different approaches on the git mailing list before starting the development.  I just wanted to hear your opinion as well.

Comment: @dsimic I will follow the discussion there (better than in the comments of this old question)

Comment: @VonC Great, thanks.  Please note that it will take a while before I get it discussed on the mailing list, i.e. before I start working on the whole thing, as I already noted above.

Comment: @VonC I just spent some time making `vim` understand the editing of `git` object notes and branch descriptions better, by using an appropriate file type and syntax.  As a result, implementing and upstreaming another patch for `vim` just went into my rather lengthy TO-DO list. :)

Comment: @dsimic Great, please let me know when you have a link in the Git mailing list.

Comment: @VonC Sure, I'll post the links here when the time comes.

Comment: @VonC Maybe you'd like to have a look at a somewhat [related patch](https://lore.kernel.org/git/3cbc78bb5729f304b30bf37a18d1762af553aa00.1708022441.git.dsimic@manjaro.org/T/#u) that I just sent to the git mailing list.

Comment: @dsimic Nicely done! I will follow that patch with interest.

Comment: @VonC Thank you, I'm glad that you like it. :)

Comment: @VonC I just submitted [version 2](https://lore.kernel.org/git/6e1c3f2c5816f09aab561bc7dec2b7455d70aaec.1708087213.git.dsimic@manjaro.org/T/#u) of the patch to the git mailing list.

Comment: @dsimic Great! Nice touch on the reflog entry created when renaming a branch.

Comment: @VonC Thanks!  The patch reviews and suggestions on the git mailing list helped a lot, which I'm so grateful for.  I'm looking forward to the completely reworked git-branch(1) man page, which is currently the ultimate goal.  BTW, here's [another patch](https://lore.kernel.org/git/b0577267402f6177d8ba5646e12d7691437e6e8f.1708060779.git.dsimic@manjaro.org/T/#u) on the git mailing list. :)

Answer (score 6):

Hit this on terminal. This will display branches with description if your branch has some description.

**Step 1:**

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

**Step 2:**
Put this

```
alias git-describe-branches='for line in $(git branch); do 
     description=$(git config branch.$line.description)
     if [ -n "$description" ]; then
       echo "$line     $description"
     fi
done'
```

**Step 3:**

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Step 4:**

```
git-describe-branches
```

**OR**

```
for line in $(git branch); do 
     description=$(git config branch.$line.description)
     if [ -n "$description" ]; then
       echo "$line     $description"
     fi
done
```

Note:

1. Run this in git working directory.
2. Will show description if your branch has description.

Answer (score 3):

to check branch description in just one line

```
git config branch.<branch_name>.description
```

Comment: This is the same idea as the aliases I mention at [the end of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15062356/6309), I suppose.

Comment: I think this is easier to understand, at least for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been ages since this was asked, but I just started using branch descriptions and came across this looking for display ideas.

**regarding bash script answer**: It only prints branches that have a description. I want to mimic `git branch` output but with descriptions as well.

**regarding perl script answer**: Formatting fails with longer branch names. It also outputs screwiness if you are in a detached HEAD state.

I had a go in python and this is what I came up with. It solves my issues with the previous answers.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import sys


def git(*args):
    return subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/git'] + list(args)).strip()


try:
    branches = git('branch').split('\n')
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    sys.exit(1)

longest = len(max(branches, key=len))
for branch in branches:
    active = '*' if branch[0] == '*' else ''
    branch = branch.lstrip(' *')
    try:
        desc = git('config', 'branch.'+branch+'.description')
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print '{:2}{}'.format(active, branch)
    else:
        print '{:2}{:{}}  {}'.format(active, branch, longest, desc)
```

exhibit A

```
[user|host ~/git/repo((HEAD detached at origin/master))]% git bd
* (HEAD detached at origin/master)
  branch_a
  delete_this_after_a_little_while_pls_thx_bye    long branch description
  other_branch
  yay_branches_amirite                            PR under review
```

exhibit B

```
[user|host ~/git/repo(other_branch_name)]% git bd
  branch_a
  delete_this_after_a_little_while_pls_thx_bye    long branch description
* other_branch
  yay_branches_amirite                            PR under review
```

exhibit C

```
[user|host ~/non_git_repo]% git bd
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Comment: Interesting alternative to my 4-years old answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

I took inspiration from Sahil Gulati and made this:

```
alias git-describe-branches='git branch | while read line; do 
     description=$(git config branch.$(echo "$line" | sed "s/\* //g").description)
     echo "$line     $description"
done'
```

Example:

```
$ git-describe-branches 
bugfixdatum     
feat32     
feat53     
feat56     
* feat57     Projektlista
feat65     
feat72     
feat75     Prevent replacing lager with empty inventering
master     
referens
```

This also prints branches without description, and the sed command is because current branch need special treatment due to the asterisk character.

Comment: Best soln until now, until the "git branch --verbose-format" patch is implemented. Your soln also takes care of the issues with bash script soln that @penchant talks about. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

bash command:

```
eval "git config branch.`git branch --show-current`.description"
```

if with alias:

```
alias gs='git status && eval "git config branch.`git branch --show-current`.description"'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple script I'm using. It shows all branches in a nice table highlighting the current one. A prefix could also be passed in the cmd line to show only a subset of branches.

```
#!/bin/python3

from sys import argv
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from subprocess import check_output
import os
import sys

def format_table(table):
    table.field_names = ["branch", "description"]
    table.align["branch"] = "l"
    table.align["description"] = "l"

def show_branches(prefix):
    table = PrettyTable()
    format_table(table)
    G = "\033[0;32;40m" # GREEN
    N = "\033[0m" # Reset

    try:
        branches = check_output(['git', 'branch']).decode('utf')
    except:
        sys.exit(1)

    for branch in branches.splitlines():
        if prefix not in branch:
            continue

        curr_branch = '*' in branch
        branch_name = branch.strip() if not curr_branch else branch.strip().split(' ')[1]
        try:
            output = check_output(['git', 'config', f'branch.{branch_name}.description']).decode('utf')
            desc = os.linesep.join([s for s in output.splitlines() if s])
        except:
            desc = '---'
        if curr_branch:
            table.add_row([G+branch_name, desc+N])
        else:
            table.add_row([N+branch_name+N, desc+N])

    # Done
    print(table)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prefix = argv[1] if len(argv) > 1 else ''
    show_branches(prefix)
```

Comment: Works great. Maybe use decode('utf-8') instead of decode('utf') ?

Answer (score 0):

I can still not find a good solution in 2017.

I came up with another solution though.
The first line is required after changing the current branch in order to update the BRANCH_DESCRIPTION file. It just runs the edit-description tool with a "do nothing editor". Then you can simply get the description from the file `.git/BRANCH_DESCRIPTION`.

```
(export GIT_EDITOR=':';git branch --edit-description); 
cat $GITREPOSITORY/.git/BRANCH_DESCRIPTION
```

NOTE:

This might not be documented/stable behavior.

Comment: `$ g alias be 'branch --edit-description';
$ g alias bd '!(export GIT_EDITOR=cat; git be | grep -v "#")'` works. Cheers

Comment: `cat .git/config`

Answer (score 0):

I also took inspiration from Sahil Gulati on my answer. I wanted the script to also include branches that have no description and make it look all pretty like the usual `git branch` does, so I added some colors and padding.

So you could do something like this.

Create a script, e.g. `~/git-branch-show-descriptions.sh` and add execution rights.

```
branches=$(git branch --format="%(refname:short)")
current=$(git branch --show-current)
no_color='\033[0m'
green='\033[0;32m'
pad="                               "
pad_length=31

for line in $branches
    do
        description=$(git config branch.$line.description)
        padded_line="${line}${pad}"
        formatted_line="${padded_line:0:pad_length} ${description}"
        [ $line = $current ] \
            && echo -e "* ${green}${formatted_line}${no_color}" \
            || echo    "  $formatted_line"
    done
```

Add the alias to `~/.bashrc`

```
alias git-branch-show-descriptions=~/git-branch-show-descriptions.sh
```

And source it or restart bash.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This should show descriptions to all branches that have them and just the name for the ones that don't. The selected branch will be shown in green.