# How to manage role of branch in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm using Git to manage my project but I had a problem with role of branches. Any branch in Git can push code of them to remote/master branch, so it make me confuse when I merge to stable versions. Because may be a developer pushed to my master branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: If it helps here is another website that I use - http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model and if you prefer to see the merges visually - something like BitBucket, GitHub or Stash has `pull` requests so that you can see the merges and approve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition of basic branch management, you can:

- make sure the remote doesn't accept non-fast-forward merge: so at least if a developer directly pushes new commits to `origin/master`, it would be commits easily merged to the new branch (that forces a developer to first rebase his/her work on top of `origin/master` before attempting a push).
  See "[What's a “fast-forward” in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4684404/6309)" and "[Why does git use fast-forward merging by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850413/6309)".
- you can more easily separate dev branches by creating them in their own **namespace**: `username/master` instead of `master`, keeping `master` for being an (untouched) mirror image of `origin/master`.
- you can add a description to a branch, leaving one more clue as to what that branch is for: see "[Branch descriptions in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858853/6309)": `git branch --edit-description`. That information will be pushed along to a remote repo, for others to see.
- finally, you can choose and follow a git workflow ([like git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)) in order to manage the convention around branch usage.

Comment: Good advice but I don't think the OP is knowledgeable enough to apply it. There's a lot of technicality like "fast-forward" etc. which will confuse rather than help.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim you do realize that this answer is intended to be helpful to *more* than *just* the OP, right? Plus, those "technicalities" might prompt the OP to discover a bit more about Git, which is always good.

Comment: I do. My comment however, was mostly directed to the OP to whom your detailed answer might, in my opinion, seem overwhelming.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim Then I agree with you; Hopefully, it will open new horizons for the OP or others in their Git discovery journey.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: sorry, what's OP means?