# Storing repository meta-data in GIT

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm want to store metadata per GIT repository such as which branches to use during CI/CD processes.

It seems natural to store the relevant metadata within each GIT repository, however, then the metadata itself is branched.

If I store the metadata within GIT, then each time the file is changed i.e. each time it is merged back into the master branch, the merge will trigger a build.

Question: Is there a way to ignore a specific file in (all repositories') build trigger?

I would also appreciate comments/answers on other ways to solve the root problem - storing metadata on the repositories to be used by CI/CD processes.

Alternative I am considering: Store this metadata in a database, however, then, as the metadata will not be stored near the branches, I am afraid developers may forget to set or update it.

Comment: How about storing the information with `git config --local --add <var> <value>`. That will store the information within `.git/config`

Comment: @dgw won't that cause the config to be stored in the local client only?

Comment: Yes. That would store the information locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I used was to create and update build definitions automatically, via code in a dedicated Devops service I wrote and set/add the ignore pattern for all builds (along with other definitions in build based on config in GIT repos).

Answer (score 6):

If you are talking about *metadata* (meaning not a *data* stored in a *file*), you might consider [`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes)

> Adds, removes, or reads notes attached to objects, without touching the objects themselves.
>
> By default, notes are saved to and read from `refs/notes/commits`, but this default can be overridden.

That way, you can push those metadata, as you would for regular commits and their files.

The other workaround would be to [associate a description to a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858853/6309): that is another metadata which can be pushed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these options.

Comment: Notes are attached to a reference. I see no easy way to find a note among millions commits. `git notes list` is unreadable machine dump.

Comment: @gavenkoa True: you would need to encourage a standardized format or template for notes. That could include specific headers, keywords, or tags that make it easier to search and parse the notes.

Comment: @gavenkoa Or you could create and maintain an index of notes, possibly in a separate file or a dedicated branch. This index could be updated automatically via a CI/CD pipeline or hooks. The index can be a simple markdown or text file with links to the specific commits the notes are attached to, along with a brief description of each note.