# HOWTO add file to all branch one time (git/github/gitlab)?

Tags: git

add a file for git repo all branch.

Before , i add .gitignore per branch, I will do this:

```
    vi .gitignore
    git add .gitignore
    git commit -m "add .gitignore"
    git push origin branch1
```

I feel very troublesome.

If a repo has some branchs , i want to add .gitignore to all branch quickly. how i can do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GIT - how to keep a file common across all branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876142/git-how-to-keep-a-file-common-across-all-branches)