# git - add a new file to all existing branches

Tags: git

Let's say I have a repo called `tool_crda`. I have branched it a number of times. I just add a file named `manual` to branch `master` which is a common guide to use `tool_crda`. What I want is to have that file `manual` available regardless of the branch I'm working on (for now I don't have the need to modify that file).

Is there a simple way to make that `manual` file available on all branches (for now whenever switching away from `master` that `manual` file is gone as well).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876142/git-how-to-keep-a-file-common-across-all-branches) seems to be a related question - but I wonder if there is a simpler alternative.

Comment: It kind of sounds like you just want a second repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think without that hook its not possible to make that file available in all branches. What you can do is to make a new branch and add that files you need in that branch. After changing merge that branch in your actual branch. I think thats the easiest way to solve your Problem.